# Mac OS deploy Django + Apache on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy Django and Apache to Amazon EC2 server. Currently, i have already got the AWS account and lunched the instance on server. But the problem is that i cannot find a tutorial about how to deploy Django and Apache to Amazon EC2 WITH Mac OS, all i can find are Linux system deploying tutorials. Where can i find deploying tutorial for Mac OS?

Comment: For the most part, OSX does have most of the linux tools available or they can be easily installed via macports or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Terminal to SSH into your AWS EC2 environment. All commands past there are 100% platform based (ubuntu, amazon linux, red hat, etc).

You wouldn't use any Mac OS commands besides creating the SSH connection. There's a tutorial on how to do that through the EC2 console.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Dose this mean i can use nearly all the essential commands on Mac OSX the same as Linux?

Comment: The commands aren't much different between the two (depending on your flavor of Linux), but once connected through SSH you'd only be able to use the Linux commands.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. After days of study, i think i made it clear that what commands to use when operating the sever is not related to what i OS i am using locally, but what the Amazon EC2 is. And after i SSH to the sever, i should input commands exactly corresponding to the Amazon EC2. :)

Comment: Perfect! Also Amazon's documentation is a great resource for diving into this stuff. They also have a lot of recorded webinars on YouTube as well. Just search AWS EC2 *insert what you're trying to do*.